# how to get access to the siblings when using each in jquery

Tags: jquery, each

Consider the code below

```
 $('.item_select').each(List);

 function List() {

        var x= this.siblings('.fooClass');
}
```

When I try to access the siblings this way, I get the error
*"Object doesn't support property or method 'siblings' "*

How do I get access to the siblings of the 'this' object ?

Comment: Try wrapping this in $(this) ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.item_select').each(List);

 function List() {

        var x= $(this).siblings('.fooClass');
}
```